# How to pass an extra argument to UDF using withColumn

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

How can I pass an extra argument to my UDF using withColumn

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["aaa","1"],
  ["bbb","2"],
  ["ccc","5"]
]).toDF("text","id")

def title(x,y):
   if y:
      x = x.title()
   return x

title_udf = udf(lambda x: title(x,y), StringType())
spark.udf.register('title_udf', title_udf)

df = df.withColumn('text_title',title_udf('text',True)
```

When i try this i get an error: `Invalid argument, not a string or column....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

udf s can recognize only row elements. So to pass a fixed argument you have to use lit() function. Also your udf definition has to be corrected. Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["aaa","1"],
  ["bbb","2"],
  ["ccc","5"]
]).toDF("text","id")

def title(x,y):
   if y:
      x = x.title()
   return x

title_udf = F.udf(title, StringType())

df = df.withColumn('text_title',title_udf('text',F.lit(True)))

 df.show()
+----+---+----------+
|text| id|text_title|
+----+---+----------+
| aaa|  1|       Aaa|
| bbb|  2|       Bbb|
| ccc|  5|       Ccc|
+----+---+----------+
```

As indicated by @powers in the comment, if this output is your ultimate purpose, ,then you can do this without a udf using initcap() function

```
df = df.withColumn("text_title",F.when(F.lit(True),F.initcap(F.col('text'))).otherwise(F.col('text')))
```

You can also use other columns as condition like the 'id' column

```
df = df.withColumn("text_title",F.when(F.col('id')>2,F.initcap(F.col('text'))).otherwise(F.col('text')))
```

Comment: @Raghu - great answer +1.  As an extra credit assignment, you might also want to explain how to solve this without using a UDF.  UDFs should always be avoided when possible and I think this problem can be solved with Spark native functions.

Comment: @Powers - thanks for the hint.. I always assume that the given data is a toy example :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid udf using **`initcap`** inbuilt function.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["aaa","1"],
  ["bbb","2"],
  ["ccc","5"]
]).toDF("text","id")

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("text_title",initcap(col("text"))).show()
#+----+---+----------+
#|text| id|text_title|
#+----+---+----------+
#| aaa|  1|       Aaa|
#| bbb|  2|       Bbb|
#| ccc|  5|       Ccc|
#+----+---+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware if it but it was just an example for the UDF